# Determinant of a $4\times4$ matrix without using triangular method if possible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Find the unique value of $x$ for which
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}-6 & -1 & -3 & 6\\
5 & -5 & x & 6\\
-8 & -4 & -8 & 2\\
-5 & 1 & -6 & -4
\end{pmatrix}=0.$$

Comment: Where are you blocked ?

Comment: Do you know how to find the determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix?  Knowing this, do you know how to find the determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix?  Knowing this, do you then know how to find the determinant of a $4\times 4$ matrix?  [Knowledge of Laplacian Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) will be useful here.

Comment: i know how to find it with triangular method and if there are zeros in the matrix thats why i got lost

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend this website https://matrixcalc.org/en/ to analyze matrices.

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}-6 & -1 & -3 & 6\\
5 & -5 & \frac{1100}{210} & 6\\
-8 & -4 & -8 & 2\\
-5 & 1 & -6 & -4
\end{pmatrix}=0.$$

[Leibniz-Formel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants):

$-6 \cdot(-5) \cdot (-8) \cdot (-4)\\
-(-6) \cdot (-5) \cdot 2 \cdot (-6)\\
-(-6) \cdot x \cdot (-4) \cdot (-4)\\
+(-6) \cdot x \cdot 2 \cdot 1\\
+(-6) \cdot 6 \cdot (-4) \cdot (-6)\\
-(-6) \cdot 6 \cdot (-8) \cdot 1\\
-(-1) \cdot 5 \cdot (-8) \cdot (-4)\\
+(-1) \cdot 5 \cdot 2 \cdot (-6)\\
+(-1) \cdot x \cdot (-8) \cdot (-4)\\
-(-1) \cdot x \cdot 2 \cdot (-5)\\
-(-1) \cdot 6 \cdot (-8) \cdot (-6)\\
+(-1) \cdot 6 \cdot (-8) \cdot (-5)\\
+(-3) \cdot 5 \cdot (-4) \cdot (-4)\\
-(-3) \cdot 5 \cdot 2 \cdot 1\\
-(-3) \cdot (-5) \cdot (-8) \cdot (-4)\\
+(-3) \cdot (-5) \cdot 2 \cdot (-5)\\
+(-3) \cdot 6 \cdot (-8) \cdot 1\\
-(-3) \cdot 6 \cdot (-4) \cdot (-5)\\
-6 \cdot 5 \cdot (-4) \cdot (-6)\\
+6 \cdot 5 \cdot (-8) \cdot 1\\
+6 \cdot (-5) \cdot (-8) \cdot (-6)\\
-6 \cdot (-5) \cdot (-8) \cdot (-5)\\
-6 \cdot x \cdot (-8) \cdot 1\\
+6 \cdot x \cdot (-4) \cdot (-5)\\
=210 \cdot x-1100$

$$210 \cdot x -1100 \Rightarrow x = \frac{1100}{210}$$

The method of [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) or the [Bareiss algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bareiss_algorithm) provide the same result.

Good luck :)

Comment: would you mind giiving me a direction of how you got there? it'd be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I hope it helps you ....

Comment: is there any way this can be solved with reduced row echelon form or the triangular form

Answer (score 1):

Using [SymPy Live](http://live.sympy.org):

```
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> M = Matrix([[-6, -1, -3, 6], [5, -5, x, 6], [-8, -4, -8, 2], [-5, 1, -6, -4]])
>>> M
[-6  -1  -3  6 ]
[              ]
[5   -5  x   6 ]
[              ]
[-8  -4  -8  2 ]
[              ]
[-5  1   -6  -4]         
>>> M.det()
210*x - 1100
```